# Twitter Bootstrap spans overflowing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/jgehrs/MgcDU/3103/

I have this block of code, which should result in 4 equally sized spans all lined up horizontally, but as you can see, the 4th block is pushed down to a new row.  I've used bootstrap for a few days now, and this is the first time I've seen this.

```
<div id='middle' class='row'>
  <div class='span3'>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='span3'>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='span3'>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='span3'>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
```

[image: spans overflowing]

Edit: Here is a jsFiddle showing the problem.

Comment: Is there a border? That may break it.

Comment: There is a 1px border, but I get the exact same result with no border.

Comment: You may want to make a JSfiddle. If it is not the border, perhaps it is another style.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just added the JSfiddle link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fluid layout works with percentages. You can try `<div class="row-fluid">` that fixed it for me.

Comment: Yup, looks like that was the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks for this, no mention that you need row-fluid with container-fluid in the docs. No wonder my columns were overflowing

Comment: In my case the error was that a client had moved a heading into the row section. This answer helped me to see it. So row-fluid is necessary, and must be at the right place ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3105/)

The css adding the border is done after the grid system calculates widths and causes the element to wrap.  I placed a class on the inner div and applied the border to the inner element.  I also wrapped the row in a div container to give it a fixed layout.

```
.myBorder { border: 1px solid gray; }

<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='span3'>
    <div class="myBorder">1</div>
  </div>
```

[Elements with Borders Wrap](http://sentientmatter.com/blog/borders-in-bootstrap/)

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.  Set the width of .container to 300 or 500px to see what I mean, they wrap again.  Isn't the whole point of the row/span system of Twitter Bootstrap to split the spans into percentage widths no matter what the parent container width is or am I misunderstanding what Bootstrap's grid system is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the row in a div with class `container`. Additionally, change the class of the div row to `row-fluid`, like so:

```
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row-fluid'>
      <div class='span3'>
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='span3'>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class='span3'>
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
      <div class='span3'>
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Look here for demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3107/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is close to what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/F7zRy/

As @kyriakos noted you want to use `<div class='row-fluid'>` if you want a fluid grid, and optionally wrap everything with `<div class="container-fluid">` if you want your grid to fill the entire window.

And best not to use borders because they add extra width the columns and will cause wrapping. If you need to use borders, use border-box

Good luck!